# Dados alterados no banco não são apresentados no DataTable do PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando desabilitar a cache do JPA (EclipseLink 2.5.2) através do "persistence.xml", mas não está funcionando.

Alterações feitas nas tabelas, externamente à aplicação, não são apresentadas no DataTable do PrimeFaces 5.0 com JSF 2.2.

Ambiente: Netbeans 8.0.2 + GlassFish 4.1 (com Pool de conexões)

O que pode estar faltando?

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="br.com.empresa_Teste_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/teste</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.refresh" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O problema não pode ser no seu *Managed Beans*, que está armazenando a lista, sem buscá-la no banco de dados quando a tela é atualizada? Qual o escopo do MB? Como está implementado o getter da lista?

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas! No projeto que estou testando, as classes foram geradas automaticamente pelo NetBeans. Eu já havia testado os diferentes tipos de escopo, mas não havia percebido que o gerador não cria a anotação `@ManagedBean` na classe MB. Adicionando esta anotação e passando o escopo para `@ViewScoped` funcionou como eu desejava.

Comment: Ótimo. Se quiser colocar sua solução como resposta para sua própria pergunta, fique à vontade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No projeto que estou testando, as classes foram geradas automaticamente pelo NetBeans. Eu já havia testado os diferentes tipos de escopo, mas não havia percebido que o gerador não cria a anotação `@ManagedBean` na classe MB. Adicionando esta anotação e passando o escopo para `@ViewScoped` funcionou como eu desejava.